# Runtime detection of Linux/ARM "kuser_helper" functions

Tags: c, linux, arm, atomic

Normally on Linux/ARM, a special page mapped at `0xffff0000` is used for implementing the "read TLS pointer" operation, atomic compare-and-swap, and memory barriers. This system is called "kuser helpers" (`CONFIG_KUSER_HELPERS`) and is necessary to work around the lack of support for atomic compare-and-swap in earlier arm models. However, recent kernel versions offer an option to disable this feature on the principle that it's a security risk (facilitating attacks based on return to a fixed executable address, since these functions are not subject to ASLR); this option can be used if all applications are built to make direct use of synchronization instructions available on newer ARM models.

My problem is that I want to be able to support both old ARM models (which lack synchronization instructions) and new hardened kernels (which lack kuser helpers) with the same binaries, so I'm looking for a reliable way, from userspace, to detect the availability of the kuser helper page (using it if it's available, and assuming if it's not that the newer instructions must be available). Reliable excludes things like `/proc` that might not always be available. Is there any way to probe for the existence of the kuser helper page short of trying to use it and trapping `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: To clarify, you want to cover < armv6 right?

Comment: On arm < v6, kuser helper is mandatory and can't be turned off. But yes I want binaries that can work on any v4t and up.

Comment: So why don't you write a wrapper checking version via /proc/cpuinfo and doing either ldrex/strex or or cmpxchg stuff? I wonder if it is a realistic concern to worry about ldrex/strex not working (check last paragraph) https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/arm/swp_emulation

Comment: What is wrong with `SIGSEGV`?  You other question could also use `SIGILL` to test for `LDREX/STREX`.  You only need to install the handlers during the *probe* phase. *KUSER_HELPERS* have more than helpers for *cmpxchg*.  If the CPU is ARMv5 (or less), you need it.  Only if the CPU is not ARMv5 you don't.  `LDREX/STREX` is added in ARMv6.  As per auselen's link, you need to be careful about the memory you are using `LDREX/STREX` with.

Comment: Probably `mmap(0xffff0000);` will return 0xffff0000 on systems without KUSER_HELPERS, but I would just use the `SIGSEGV`.  It would have been smart to keep an empty page mapped with only a version number that was not an op-code.  But now we have kernels without the page.

Comment: As noted in the question, `/proc` might not always be available, e.g. before it's mounted. The code I'm working on is in libc and it's fragile to try to guarantee that no code which might use atomics is called before `/proc` is mounted (also, opening it could fail due to exceeding fd limit, etc., so it's not safe to rely on this).

Comment: As for handling `SIGSEGV`, if the signal is blocked or ignored at program entry, unblocking or unignoring it to make the check would change program semantics. This is rather an obscure corner case that (probably) nobody cares about, but it would still be wrong, and it's basically impossible to work around, I think.

Comment: Also note that I would like to *prefer* kuser helpers when they're available, and only use ldrex/strex directly when they're not. This is for several reasons: (1) kuser helpers optimize out the barrier on non-smp machines, (2) per the official documentation, ldrex/strex are not valid on non-smp hardware and might not work; the kernel can work around this if necessary better than I can, and (3) ARM has a history of deprecating instructions and changing things in incompatible ways and I don't really trust ldrex/strex to keep working on future models.

Comment: @artlessnoise: I kinda doubt the kernel lets you `mmap` in the kernel address range, but maybe... If that works it would be an easy way to work around missing kuser helpers: just add them yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

the vectors page is set up in arch/arm/kernel/traps.c:early_trap_init() during kernel initialisation and will still be present, just without the helpers, so you shouldn't get a SEGV in the first place; for the same reason the mmap trick won't work (i haven't checked either of these assumptions).

but: the vectors page is initialised to zero by early_alloc_aligned(), so you're lucky, since the number of kuser_helpers at 0xffff0ffc will not be filled in and is thus zero.

tl;dr: read the number of kuser helpers from 0xffff0ffc. if zero => no support for them

Comment: Sadly grsec kernels remove the mapping entirely rather than just omitting the functions, so on them it crashes...